# How I can align a text and a image with bottom-line in HTML?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I run Code A, and get the result Image A.

I hope to align these text and  image with bottom-line, just like Image B,  how can I do?

**Code A**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="image" src="Image/edit.png" />
<input type="image" src="Image/save.png" />
<input type="image" src="Image/cancel.png" />
```

**Image A**

[image]

****Image B****

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways to do so:-

1. **use *flex* property**

```css
.iNeedGf
{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
/*justify content is for horizontal alignment not for vertical alignment just making it clear since the person above have written it wrong*/
}
```

---

```html
<div class='iNeedGf'>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="image" src="Image/edit.png" />
    <input type="image" src="Image/save.png" />
    <input type="image" src="Image/cancel.png" />
</div>
```

2. **use relative position**

```css
[type='image']/*this is attribute selector it selects all the elements that have attribute __type__ set to __image__*/
{
position:relative;/*allow you to use left-right-top-bottom properties*/
top:10px;/*change this according to your needs*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `display: flex`. Wrap your tags in an element (such as a `<div>`) and apply `align-items: center`.

Example.

```css
.example-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="image" src="Image/edit.png" />
    <input type="image" src="Image/save.png" />
    <input type="image" src="Image/cancel.png" />
</div>
```

If you continue to have problems, check that none of your elements have a `margin` or `padding`.